# Use methods in classes

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods

I have two classes. Let them be Directory and File for example. There are my own custom classes, not a part of .NET Framework.
So, Directory has Title field and list of files. File has several fields too.

Where should I place methods which will return list of files by directory title for example,
in Directory class or in File class?

i.e. which of these is better:

```
public List<Files> Directory.GetFiles(string directoryTitle){...}
public List<Files> File.GetFilesByDirectory(string directoryTitle){...}
```

and why?

Comment: It should return `IEnumerable<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, not `List<T>`.

Comment: What's wrong with [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)?

Comment: @Groo - it's just an example. I've meant such situation with any classes.

Comment: @Tannheuser - but the answer will depend on the domain you are modelling. What may be true for File and Directory will not be true for e.g., Dog and Cat. There is no single correct answer for "any classes".

Comment: @ShellShock - my fail, of course not "any classes" but classes which are related to each other. Like User and Order and others.

Answer (score 4):

Two thoughts:

first, it's the Directory that knows about listing files, so that's where that should live.

Second, try to stick to interfaces for your return types - IList instead of List. That gives you more flexibility for returning different kinds of lists AND for unit testing.

Comment: As @SLaks mentioned above, a readonly collection (or an array, or `IEnumerable`) would be an even better choice for the return type.

Comment: @Groo: Not an array; arrays are not read-only and must be sized to fit.

Comment: @SLaks: a readonly collection ***or*** an array. I would personally only consider `IEnumerable`, but `Directory.GetFiles` (as well as many other BCL classes) returns an array. If nothing else, one needs additional effort to resize it, compared to a `List`.

Comment: @Groo: The array-returning framework methods predate generics.  Modern code should not return arrays, since it will need to resize the array to fit after populating it (unlike a collection)

Answer (score 0):

I would say first is *better*

```
public List<Files> Directory.GetFiles(string directoryTitle){...}
```

Since File itself should not be aware where it is located and Directory is aware which files it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Where you actually put them is your own prerogative, but I'd say it is more semantically sound to use the first version in this instance: `Directory.GetFiles`. The NET framework actually exposes a `Directory` class which you could use as an example of this, containing such a method.

It would also seem kind of counter-intuitive doing it the other way, all else aside, considering that the directory instance already contains a list of known files.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally leave both of those classes alone and create a 3rd class to do the work which maximises the opportunity for code reuse. Call it DirectoryFileFinder or something similar.